# Blank UITableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to complete a simple app with a tableview that lists three people. But all I get when I run it is a blank table. I'm not sure what's wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

here's my code: https://github.com/student511/UITableView

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're redefining the array of people.  Remove the line:

```
self.people = [NSArray array];
```

From your TableViewController.